# Rails 4 digit pin login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, integer

I was experimenting with the idea last month of a user being able to input their email and a 4 digit pin to login to their Dashboard.

Since the app doesn't require top security and the 4 digit pin would work I wasn't sure how to implement this on the controller side as I would like to have each parts to the pin in their own input field.

The fields I have are..

```
<%= u.password_field 'pin[]' %>
<%= u.password_field 'pin[]' %>
<%= u.password_field 'pin[]' %>
<%= u.password_field 'pin[]' %>
```

I'll run some client side validation to make sure all fields are input, and perhaps some Model validation if I sent an `attr_accessor` on the model for the 4 parts to the pin? - Would that work?

Basically from the inputs above I just want access to a `pin` variable but all previous attempts have lead me to receiving a `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` error.

Answer (score 1):

1. check params, I think "pin" is array
2. you can add few variables (attr_accessile a, b, c, d) and before_validation do pin = [a,b,c,d].join